# Custom UIView doesnt show

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have very simple UIView that creating the box, but what is happen is the UIView does not show at all, here is my code on `sharingButtons.m`

```
-(void)createContainer{

winWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;


buttonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, winWidth, 20)];
buttonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


[self.view addSubview:buttonContainer];

 }


-(void)createButton{
[self createContainer];
}
```

and here is my `sharingButtons.h`

```
 @interface SocialSharing : UIViewController {
int winWidth;
 }

- (void)createButton;
- (void)createContainer;

#pragma mark - Properties

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView* buttonContainer;

@end
```

And `createButton` method is called from `MyViewControler.m` on `viewDidLoad`

Is any wrong with my code??

## EDITED

Here is my code on MyViewControler.m

```
- (void)loadSocialSharingButton {

socialButtons = [[SocialSharing alloc] init];

[socialButtons createButton];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

[self loadSocialSharingButton];

}
```

Sorry I just learn about obj c :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show the code from MyViewController.c, where you call createButton?

Comment: Perhaps you button is hidden under a navigation bar (at the top). If ou make it 200px tall rather than 20px, do you see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `buttonContainer` is not visible is, it is not loaded in your view hierarchy.

To make it visible you should add it as subview. In `MyViewController.m` in `viewDidLoad` add the following line after `[self loadSocialSharingButton];`

```
[self.view addSubview:socialButtons.buttonContainer];
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Wow, what a silly me, I should know about it, and it work perfectly, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `SocialSharing` is subclass of **UIViewController**.

And you add your `buttonContainer view` to this `SocialSharing Controller`,this controller is not on screen if you just call

```
socialButtons = [[SocialSharing alloc] init];

[socialButtons createButton];
```

So,you can not see anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently @ MyViewController and But you are loading your custom view @ SocialSharing ViewController, Both ViewController are distinct and you can't just get your custom view at social sharing to MyViewController by initializing it.

You have change SocialSharing class as sub class of UIView and initialize this view and add to subview of MyViewController.

SocialSharing.h

```
@interface SocialSharing : UIView {
int winWidth;
}
- (instancetype)createButton;
#pragma mark - Properties
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView* buttonContainer;
@end
```

SocialSharing.m

```
- (instancetype)createButton
{
   winWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
   self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, winWidth, 20)];
   if (self) {
     buttonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:];
     buttonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     [self addSubview:buttonContainer];
   }
   return self;
}
```

MyViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self loadSocialSharingButton];
  }
- (void)loadSocialSharingButton {
  socialButtons = [SocialSharing alloc] createButton];
  [self.view addSubView:socialButtons];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In an iOS App, only one `ViewController` at a time is active. And as you are at `MyViewController`, so `MyViewController` is active, if you want to navigate to any other view controller than you need to present or push the instance of same. Doing so will make the other view controller as active.

In your case the problem is your `SocialSharing` is a subclass of `UIViewController` as it is created as `SocialSharing : UIViewController` and it's not active, so adding any view over it won't be visible as the instance of `SocialSharing` is not `pushed/ presented`. If you need to show the view from SocialSharing than either you subclass it from `UIView` or push/ present the instance of `SocialSharing` to make it's view active and visible.